# Sensor compatibility with power source

Tags: sensors

I have a sensor whose datasheet mentions that it should be connected to 5V Vcc.

A green LED glows on the sensor when it is powered from the source at 5V.

However, even if I power it with 3.3V, still the green LED glows.

Does this affect the working of the sensor in any way?

If somebody could please let me know about this, I would be very much thankful.

Comment: Are you referring to a sensor module? I yet to come across  stand alone sensors with an integrated LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it says 5V power it up with 5V.** The fact that the LED is glowing does not necessarily mean that the sensor is operating as it should.

You can only safely say that the LED is receiving enough voltage to operate (nothing more nothing less), unless you have the manual of the sensor that says otherwise (e.g. if the greenlight on the LED is indicative of appropriate power supply).